# Equivalent of Format of VB in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

What will be the equivalent code for `Format(iCryptedByte, "000")` (VB.NET)  in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
iCryptedByte.ToString("D3");
```

Comment: Depends on `iCryptedByte` type. if it's `int` - yes, `ToString(string)` exists

Answer (score 11):

```
String.Format(format, iCryptedByte); // where format like {0:D2}
```

See MSDN [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Another very useful site for C# string formatting: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Instead of `{0:D3}` you can also use the zero placeholder, e.g. `{0:000}` will pad with zeros to minimum length of three.

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Format(iCryptedByte, "000");
```

You'll need to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Given this VB code:

```
Strings.Format(iCryptedByte, format)
```

Replace with this C# code:

```
var csformat = "{0:" + format + "}";
String.Format(csformat, iCryptedByte);
```

Answer (score 0):

see [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx)