# Excel format function equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I have an application that uses excel. The user needs to write an excel format in my application and I need to place it excel to some cells. However I need to provide an example to the user to know if the format will be correct or not.

I know in VBA there is the function FORMAT. Is there an equivalent in C# for this function?

It needs to work for example with the format `"[$-409]d.m.yy h:mm AM/PM;@"` but it has to support anything that the Excel supports.

Comment: The [Office Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) will have these functions.  You can create, format and save office documents using the COM objects.

Comment: There is a class WorksheetFunctions but it does not have the Format function in it. Do you know where else might it be?

Comment: I never said the interop libraries were intuitive. ;)  There is lots on google however.  I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ebec8732-4a5f-4780-b10c-eb1c4aff74e7/how-to-reformatting-cell-style-before-export-officeinteropexcel-library-v12) first try.

Comment: Not really helping. I know about this solution: change the format of a cell, write the value in it and than take the text. I need a solution that does not required the changing of a cell because the workbook might have track changes on it and I don't want to have the change in the track

Comment: so you want to take the value from the cell and format it in C#?

Comment: Also have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296645/equivalent-of-format-of-vb-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: I need a function to work with the example I gave in C#. Something like xxx(myValue, "[$-409]d.m.yy h:mm AM/PM;@") and will return exactly the same thing as excel would

Answer (score 1):

This was bothering me too. I didn't want to have to apply NumberFormat to the cells, paste the values and then retrieve the text.

After some investigation, I found the function that does this.

WorksheetFunction.Text: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841121.aspx

The first argument is the value that you want to format, this could be a String, DateTime, Double, Integer etc, the second argument is the Excel NumberFormat string.

```
MessageBox.Show(ExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Text(DateTime.Now, "[$-409]d.m.yy h:mm AM/PM;@"));
```